# Android Datepicker maxDate one week from today

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I am implementing DatePicker embedded on my activity. User must select one date between actual date until 7 days later.
I've built-in a DatePicker from Eclipse IDE by drag-and-drop feature on my activity and it already shows the datePicker on activity. However, I'm failing to accomplish one-week-from-now maxDate. Can anyone explain me? I've tried to fix MaxDate on XML file to 7, or Date().getTime() + 7 but without success.

Below, see left screen as what I want to reach and on right what I have:
[image: Intended]

[image: now]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setMaxDate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29) method takes in a long. As per the documentation, that long is the milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00. Thus `Date().getTime() + 7` will set the maximum date as 7 milliseconds from now.

Similarly, "7" is not valid for the [`maxDate` XML attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android%3amaxDate). This attribute takes in the maximum date in "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

Since you want the date to be 7 days from now, I'd recommend removing the XML attribute and sticking with `setMaxDate()`. You just need to correctly calculate the maximum date as a long.

Answer (score 4):

What about...

```
Date().getTime() + 604800000
```

After all, 604800000 is 7 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 (7 => seconds => minutes => hours => days OR, to be less talky, 7 days expressed in milliseconds)